Clickhouse Server throwing error - Table is in readonly mode due to static storage
I have recently created a Clickhouse cluster with 3 VMs on Google Cloud. I have Clickhouse-Keeper setup on these VMs and Clickhouse-Server (data/tables) are also created on these VMs.
I have a table which reads from kafka using Kafka Engine and then a materialized view inserts these  rows into another table (base_table).
kafka_engine_table -> materialized_view -> base_table
I am getting these errors in the Clickhouse-Server logs -
2024.04.10 11:48:51.022159 [ 69344 ] {} <Error> trace_span_db.trace_span_base (eb300851-f6e4-41fc-b734-1c77b75054d6): void DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::queueUpdatingTask(): Code: 242. DB::Exception: Table is in readonly mode due to static storage. (TABLE_IS_READ_ONLY), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. DB::Exception::Exception(DB::Exception::MessageMasked&&, int, bool) @ 0x000000000cbcedbb
1. DB::Exception::Exception<>(int, FormatStringHelperImpl<>) @ 0x0000000007668f23
2. DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::assertNotReadonly() const @ 0x000000001180e8da
3. void std::__function::__policy_invoker<void ()>::__call_impl<std::__function::__default_alloc_func<DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::StorageReplicatedMergeTree(String const&, String const&, DB::LoadingStrictnessLevel, DB::StorageID const&, String const&, DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context>, String const&, DB::MergeTreeData::MergingParams const&, std::unique_ptr<DB::MergeTreeSettings, std::default_delete<DB::MergeTreeSettings>>, DB::RenamingRestrictions, bool)::$_1, void ()>>(std::__function::__policy_storage const*) @ 0x0000000011985991
4. DB::BackgroundSchedulePool::threadFunction() @ 0x000000000fd9f367
5. void std::__function::__policy_invoker<void ()>::__call_impl<std::__function::__default_alloc_func<ThreadFromGlobalPoolImpl<false>::ThreadFromGlobalPoolImpl<DB::BackgroundSchedulePool::BackgroundSchedulePool(unsigned long, StrongTypedef<unsigned long, CurrentMetrics::MetricTag>, StrongTypedef<unsigned long, CurrentMetrics::MetricTag>, char const*)::$_0>(DB::BackgroundSchedulePool::BackgroundSchedulePool(unsigned long, StrongTypedef<unsigned long, CurrentMetrics::MetricTag>, StrongTypedef<unsigned long, CurrentMetrics::MetricTag>, char const*)::$_0&&)::'lambda'(), void ()>>(std::__function::__policy_storage const*) @ 0x000000000fda04d3
6. void* std::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<std::__thread_struct, std::default_delete<std::__thread_struct>>, void ThreadPoolImpl<std::thread>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::function<void ()>, Priority, std::optional<unsigned long>, bool)::'lambda0'()>>(void*) @ 0x000000000cc7d9ed
7. ? @ 0x00007f172bd4e609
8. ? @ 0x00007f172bc73353
 (version 24.3.2.23 (official build))
2024.04.10 11:48:51.035454 [ 69971 ] {} <Error> virtual void DB::ServerAsynchronousMetrics::updateImpl(TimePoint, TimePoint, bool, bool, AsynchronousMetricValues &): Cannot get replica delay for table: trace_span_db.trace_span_base: Code: 242. DB::Exception: Table is in readonly mode due to static storage. (TABLE_IS_READ_ONLY), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. DB::Exception::Exception(DB::Exception::MessageMasked&&, int, bool) @ 0x000000000cbcedbb
1. DB::Exception::Exception<>(int, FormatStringHelperImpl<>) @ 0x0000000007668f23
2. DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::assertNotReadonly() const @ 0x000000001180e8da
3. DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::getReplicaDelays(long&, long&) @ 0x00000000119119c4
4. DB::ServerAsynchronousMetrics::updateImpl(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l>>>, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l>>>, bool, bool, std::unordered_map<String, DB::AsynchronousMetricValue, std::hash<String>, std::equal_to<String>, std::allocator<std::pair<String const, DB::AsynchronousMetricValue>>>&) @ 0x0000000010fea4cb
5. DB::AsynchronousMetrics::update(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l>>>, bool) @ 0x000000000cce2ddd
6. void std::__function::__policy_invoker<void ()>::__call_impl<std::__function::__default_alloc_func<ThreadFromGlobalPoolImpl<true>::ThreadFromGlobalPoolImpl<DB::AsynchronousMetrics::start()::$_0>(DB::AsynchronousMetrics::start()::$_0&&)::'lambda'(), void ()>>(std::__function::__policy_storage const*) @ 0x000000000cce6538
7. void* std::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<std::__thread_struct, std::default_delete<std::__thread_struct>>, void ThreadPoolImpl<std::thread>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::function<void ()>, Priority, std::optional<unsigned long>, bool)::'lambda0'()>>(void*) @ 0x000000000cc7d9ed
8. ? @ 0x00007f172bd4e609
9. ? @ 0x00007f172bc73353
 (version 24.3.2.23 (official build))
2024.04.10 11:48:51.128274 [ 69826 ] {} <Error> PushingToViews: Failed to push block to view trace_span_db.trace_span_mv (19f2e497-c42c-4726-b568-a1246778ddee), Table is in readonly mode due to static storage
2024.04.10 11:48:51.128417 [ 69826 ] {} <Error> StorageKafka (trace_span_kafka_engine): void DB::StorageKafka::threadFunc(size_t) Code: 242. DB::Exception: Table is in readonly mode due to static storage. (TABLE_IS_READ_ONLY), Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. DB::Exception::Exception(DB::Exception::MessageMasked&&, int, bool) @ 0x000000000cbcedbb
1. DB::Exception::Exception<>(int, FormatStringHelperImpl<>) @ 0x0000000007668f23
2. DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::write(std::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context const>, bool) @ 0x00000000118df93c
3. DB::buildPushingToViewsChain(std::shared_ptr<DB::IStorage> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context const>, std::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, bool, std::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadStatusesHolder>, std::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadGroup>, std::atomic<unsigned long>*, bool, DB::Block const&) @ 0x00000000126e2621
4. DB::InterpreterInsertQuery::buildSink(std::shared_ptr<DB::IStorage> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadStatusesHolder>, std::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadGroup>, std::atomic<unsigned long>*) @ 0x0000000010ded685
5. DB::InterpreterInsertQuery::buildChain(std::shared_ptr<DB::IStorage> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, std::vector<String, std::allocator<String>> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadStatusesHolder>, std::atomic<unsigned long>*, bool) @ 0x0000000010decb07
6. DB::generateViewChain(std::shared_ptr<DB::Context const>, DB::StorageID const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadGroup>, DB::Chain&, std::shared_ptr<DB::ViewsData>, std::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadStatusesHolder>, bool, DB::Block const&, bool) @ 0x00000000126dcd2d
7. DB::buildPushingToViewsChain(std::shared_ptr<DB::IStorage> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::Context const>, std::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, bool, std::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadStatusesHolder>, std::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadGroup>, std::atomic<unsigned long>*, bool, DB::Block const&) @ 0x00000000126e039f
8. DB::InterpreterInsertQuery::buildSink(std::shared_ptr<DB::IStorage> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, std::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadStatusesHolder>, std::shared_ptr<DB::ThreadGroup>, std::atomic<unsigned long>*) @ 0x0000000010ded685
9. DB::InterpreterInsertQuery::execute() @ 0x0000000010df148b
10. DB::StorageKafka::threadFunc(unsigned long) @ 0x000000000f8e04b5
11. DB::BackgroundSchedulePool::threadFunction() @ 0x000000000fd9f367
12. void std::__function::__policy_invoker<void ()>::__call_impl<std::__function::__default_alloc_func<ThreadFromGlobalPoolImpl<false>::ThreadFromGlobalPoolImpl<DB::BackgroundSchedulePool::BackgroundSchedulePool(unsigned long, StrongTypedef<unsigned long, CurrentMetrics::MetricTag>, StrongTypedef<unsigned long, CurrentMetrics::MetricTag>, char const*)::$_0>(DB::BackgroundSchedulePool::BackgroundSchedulePool(unsigned long, StrongTypedef<unsigned long, CurrentMetrics::MetricTag>, StrongTypedef<unsigned long, CurrentMetrics::MetricTag>, char const*)::$_0&&)::'lambda'(), void ()>>(std::__function::__policy_storage const*) @ 0x000000000fda04d3
13. void* std::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<std::__thread_struct, std::default_delete<std::__thread_struct>>, void ThreadPoolImpl<std::thread>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::function<void ()>, Priority, std::optional<unsigned long>, bool)::'lambda0'()>>(void*) @ 0x000000000cc7d9ed
14. ? @ 0x00007f172bd4e609
15. ? @ 0x00007f172bc73353
 (version 24.3.2.23 (official build))

It looks like Clickhouse is able to read from Kafka however it is not able to insert data into materialized_view or base_table because of some issue with Clickhouse-Keeper OR my storage configuration.
I am using VMs with a local-ssd attached to it, and here is my storage configuration -
<clickhouse>
    <storage_configuration>
        <disks>
            <!--
            default disk is special, it always
            exists even if not explicitly
            configured here, but you can't change
            it's path here (you should use <path>
            on top level config instead)
            -->
            <default>
                <!--
                You can reserve some amount of free space
                on any disk (including default) by adding
                keep_free_space_bytes tag
                -->
                <keep_free_space_bytes>1024</keep_free_space_bytes>
            </default>
            <ebs_gp2_1>
                <!--
                disk path must end with a slash,
                folder should be writable for clickhouse user
                -->
                <path>/mnt/ebs_gp2_1/</path>
            </ebs_gp2_1>
            <ebs_gp2_2>
                <path>/mnt/ebs_gp2_2/</path>
            </ebs_gp2_2>
            <ebs_sc1_1>
                <path>/mnt/ebs_sc1_1/</path>
            </ebs_sc1_1>
        </disks>
        <policies>
            <ebs_gp2_sd> <!-- name for new storage policy -->
                <volumes>
                    <ebs_gp2_sd_volume> <!-- name of volume -->
                        <!-- 
                        we have only one disk in that volume  
                        and we reference here the name of disk
                        as configured above in <disks> section
                        -->
                        <disk>ebs_gp2_1</disk>
                    </ebs_gp2_sd_volume>
                </volumes>
            </ebs_gp2_sd>
        </policies>
    </storage_configuration>
</clickhouse>

Also I do not see any errors in the Clickhouse-Keeper logs -
2024.04.10 12:14:01.248553 [ 33516 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Receive a append_entries_request message from 3 with LastLogIndex=150291, LastLogTerm 398, EntriesLength=1, CommitIndex=150291 and Term=398
2024.04.10 12:14:01.248584 [ 33516 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: [INIT] log_idx: 150292, count: 0, log_store_->next_slot(): 150292, req.log_entries().size(): 1
2024.04.10 12:14:01.248590 [ 33516 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: [after SKIP] log_idx: 150292, count: 0
2024.04.10 12:14:01.248596 [ 33516 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: [after OVWR] log_idx: 150292, count: 0
2024.04.10 12:14:01.248604 [ 33516 ] {} <Trace> RaftInstance: append at 150292, term 398
2024.04.10 12:14:01.250988 [ 33516 ] {} <Trace> RaftInstance: wake up, durable index 150292
2024.04.10 12:14:01.251025 [ 33516 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Response back a append_entries_response message to 3 with Accepted=1, Term=398, NextIndex=150293
2024.04.10 12:14:01.251323 [ 33519 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Receive a append_entries_request message from 3 with LastLogIndex=150292, LastLogTerm 398, EntriesLength=0, CommitIndex=150292 and Term=398
2024.04.10 12:14:01.251367 [ 33519 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Response back a append_entries_response message to 3 with Accepted=1, Term=398, NextIndex=150293
2024.04.10 12:14:01.251370 [ 33523 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: commit upto 150292, current idx 150291
2024.04.10 12:14:01.251402 [ 33523 ] {} <Trace> RaftInstance: commit upto 150292, current idx 150292
2024.04.10 12:14:01.251430 [ 33523 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: DONE: commit upto 150292, current idx 150292
2024.04.10 12:14:01.597993 [ 33515 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Receive a append_entries_request message from 3 with LastLogIndex=150292, LastLogTerm 398, EntriesLength=0, CommitIndex=150292 and Term=398
2024.04.10 12:14:01.598061 [ 33515 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Response back a append_entries_response message to 3 with Accepted=1, Term=398, NextIndex=150293
2024.04.10 12:14:02.098203 [ 33521 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Receive a append_entries_request message from 3 with LastLogIndex=150292, LastLogTerm 398, EntriesLength=0, CommitIndex=150292 and Term=398
2024.04.10 12:14:02.098275 [ 33521 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Response back a append_entries_response message to 3 with Accepted=1, Term=398, NextIndex=150293
2024.04.10 12:14:02.598391 [ 33517 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Receive a append_entries_request message from 3 with LastLogIndex=150292, LastLogTerm 398, EntriesLength=0, CommitIndex=150292 and Term=398
2024.04.10 12:14:02.598461 [ 33517 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Response back a append_entries_response message to 3 with Accepted=1, Term=398, NextIndex=150293
2024.04.10 12:14:03.098579 [ 33516 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Receive a append_entries_request message from 3 with LastLogIndex=150292, LastLogTerm 398, EntriesLength=0, CommitIndex=150292 and Term=398
2024.04.10 12:14:03.098644 [ 33516 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Response back a append_entries_response message to 3 with Accepted=1, Term=398, NextIndex=150293
2024.04.10 12:14:03.598809 [ 33520 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Receive a append_entries_request message from 3 with LastLogIndex=150292, LastLogTerm 398, EntriesLength=0, CommitIndex=150292 and Term=398
2024.04.10 12:14:03.598880 [ 33520 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Response back a append_entries_response message to 3 with Accepted=1, Term=398, NextIndex=150293
2024.04.10 12:14:04.098985 [ 33519 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Receive a append_entries_request message from 3 with LastLogIndex=150292, LastLogTerm 398, EntriesLength=0, CommitIndex=150292 and Term=398
2024.04.10 12:14:04.099062 [ 33519 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Response back a append_entries_response message to 3 with Accepted=1, Term=398, NextIndex=150293
2024.04.10 12:14:04.599196 [ 33515 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Receive a append_entries_request message from 3 with LastLogIndex=150292, LastLogTerm 398, EntriesLength=0, CommitIndex=150292 and Term=398
2024.04.10 12:14:04.599284 [ 33515 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Response back a append_entries_response message to 3 with Accepted=1, Term=398, NextIndex=150293
2024.04.10 12:14:04.939884 [ 33521 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Receive a append_entries_request message from 3 with LastLogIndex=150292, LastLogTerm 398, EntriesLength=1, CommitIndex=150292 and Term=398
2024.04.10 12:14:04.939942 [ 33521 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: [INIT] log_idx: 150293, count: 0, log_store_->next_slot(): 150293, req.log_entries().size(): 1
2024.04.10 12:14:04.939950 [ 33521 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: [after SKIP] log_idx: 150293, count: 0
2024.04.10 12:14:04.939958 [ 33521 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: [after OVWR] log_idx: 150293, count: 0
2024.04.10 12:14:04.939969 [ 33521 ] {} <Trace> RaftInstance: append at 150293, term 398
2024.04.10 12:14:04.942071 [ 33521 ] {} <Trace> RaftInstance: wake up, durable index 150293
2024.04.10 12:14:04.942115 [ 33521 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Response back a append_entries_response message to 3 with Accepted=1, Term=398, NextIndex=150294
2024.04.10 12:14:04.942351 [ 33515 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: Receive a append_entries_request message from 3 with LastLogIndex=150293, LastLogTerm 398, EntriesLength=1, CommitIndex=150293 and Term=398
2024.04.10 12:14:04.942387 [ 33515 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: [INIT] log_idx: 150294, count: 0, log_store_->next_slot(): 150294, req.log_entries().size(): 1
2024.04.10 12:14:04.942396 [ 33515 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: [after SKIP] log_idx: 150294, count: 0
2024.04.10 12:14:04.942401 [ 33515 ] {} <Debug> RaftInstance: [after OVWR] log_idx: 150294, count: 0
2024.04.10 12:14:04.942408 [ 33515 ] {} <Trace> RaftInstance: append at 150294, term 398
2024.04.10 12:14:04.943765 [ 33515 ] {} <Trace> RaftInstance: wake up, durable index 150294

can you help me in figuring out why this error and any way to resolve this ?
I tried approach in this - https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/44597, but not working for me.

From looking at the code, it seems this error is specific to situations where ClickHouse tests the storage location for the data directory(s) and determines the storage is read-only or write-once:

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/b8e809ff32d1ac6081116202159bea693777fe9d/src/Storages/StorageMergeTree.cpp#L2470
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/src/Storages/IStorage.cpp#L274

I would suggest checking first that your storage configuration disks are on volumes that ClickHouse can write to - check the volumes are read-write, directories are available, permissions are correct, etc. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree#table_engine-mergetree-multiple-volumes_configure

thanks, yes on debugging more I found the issue, posted a comment on findings - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78310548/24190912

I was able to resolve this issue, just posting the findings here for community help -
So as I mentioned in the question I was anticipating issue with either Clickhouse-Keeper config (as all online references were suggesting that) or something wrong with my storage config.
To check/confirm for first I have created a new table without any storage policy and insertions into this table worked fine and the data was also replicated to all other replicas/nodes. So it was certain that issue is not with Clickhouse-Keeper config as consensus and replication is working fine.
So next needed to check if actually the issue is with the storage config ?
On debugging further the storage disk mount path, I found my storage_config was wrong and had wrong path for mount point of my attached local-ssd. With lsblk command on linux I was able to check all disks and mount paths. On correcting path insertions worked fine.
